# How do you call a function that use a subset of the current monad stack?

Tags: haskell

I have been dabbling with a text based application as a way to learn haskell. In the main part of my application I am using a combination of state, rand, and IO like this:

```
test :: StateT MyState (RandT StdGen IO) ()
```

I've already written some functions that I now want to stitch together but those functions were defined only with the monad(s) they needed opposed to the full stack. I'd like to avoid using the full set everywhere if I can help it.

Here is an example that shows the different cases I am trying to work out:

```
module Test.State where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Morph
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Random
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Monoid
import System.Random 

type MyState = Int

somethingThatModifiesState :: Int -> State MyState ()
somethingThatModifiesState x = do
  put x
  return ()

somethingThatUsesIO :: Int -> IO ()
somethingThatUsesIO x = print x

somethingInRandom :: Rand StdGen Int
somethingInRandom = getRandomR (0,10)

somethingInStateAndRand :: StateT MyState (Rand StdGen) Int
somethingInStateAndRand = do
  y <- getRandomR (0,10)
  put y
  return y

test :: StateT MyState (RandT StdGen IO) ()
test = do
  x  <- somethingInRandom            -- fail :(
  _  <- somethingThatModifiesState x -- fail :(
  _  <- somethingInStateAndRand      -- fail :(
  s  <- get -- ok!
  liftIO $ somethingThatUsesIO s -- ok!
  return()

myState :: Int
myState = 17

run = do
  g <- getStdGen
  runRandT (runStateT test myState) g
```

Googling has landed me in the Control.Monad.Morph module which seems to do the sort of things I want but I haven't been able to get a combination that works so far.

I've also been looking at the types to get some hints but it is a bit beyond what I understand at the moment.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using the `MonadState` and similar type classes?

Comment: Not so far but the example from Michael below gives me a place to start, thanks for the reply. As I mentioned below I need to do some reading to better understand what this is and how it compares with what I had been doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution here is not to use concrete transformer types like those from  `StateT` from `transformers` and `RandT` from `MonadRandom` until the end, but to build up the parts using "`mtl`-style" classes. Your `test` is sort of a textbook case for that:

```
module Test.State where

import Control.Monad 
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Random  
import System.Random 

type MyState = Int

somethingThatModifiesState :: MonadState MyState m => Int -> m ()
somethingThatModifiesState x = do
  put x
  return ()

somethingThatUsesIO :: MonadIO m => Int -> m ()
somethingThatUsesIO x = liftIO $ print x

somethingInRandom :: (MonadIO m , MonadRandom m) => m Int
somethingInRandom =  getRandomR (0,10)

somethingInStateAndRand :: (MonadState MyState m, MonadRandom m) => m Int
somethingInStateAndRand = do
  y <- getRandomR (0,10)
  put y
  return y

  -- this type is inferred
test :: (MonadRandom m, MonadIO m, MonadState MyState m) => m ()
test = do
  x  <- somethingInRandom            -- fail :(
  _  <- somethingThatModifiesState x -- fail :(
  _  <- somethingInStateAndRand      -- fail :(
  s  <- get -- ok!
  somethingThatUsesIO s -- ok!
  return()

myState :: Int
myState = 17

run = do
  g <- getStdGen
  runRandT (runStateT test myState) g

-- >>>  run
-- 4
-- (((),4),787162639 1655838864)
```

Edit added:

You can work directly with the transformers in such cases using `hoist`. Unfortunately `RandT` doesn't have an `MFunctor` instance. `Control.Monad.Trans.Random` does export a `mapRandT` which can do the work. Below I define `hoistRandT` so its type is uniform with the one `hoist` would have (this requires `RankNTypes`).

```
{-#LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Test.State where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Morph
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Random
import Control.Monad.Trans.Random

import Data.Functor.Identity
import Data.Monoid
import System.Random  

hoistRandT :: (forall r . m r -> n r) -> RandT s m a -> RandT s n a
hoistRandT = mapRandT

type MyState = Int

somethingThatModifiesState :: Int -> State MyState ()
somethingThatModifiesState x = do
  put x
  return ()

somethingThatUsesIO :: Int -> IO ()
somethingThatUsesIO x = print x

somethingInRandom :: RandT StdGen Identity Int
somethingInRandom = getRandomR (0,10)

somethingInStateAndRand :: StateT MyState (RandT StdGen Identity) Int
somethingInStateAndRand = do
  y <- getRandomR (0,10)
  put y
  return y 

test :: StateT MyState (RandT StdGen IO) ()
test = do
  x  <- lift $ hoistRandT generalize somethingInRandom 
  _  <- hoist generalize $ somethingThatModifiesState x 
  _  <- hoist (hoistRandT generalize) somethingInStateAndRand
  s  <- get
  liftIO $ somethingThatUsesIO s
  return()

myState :: Int
myState = 17

run = do
  g <- getStdGen
  runRandT (runStateT test myState) g
```

The main business is happening in `test` where I carefully tune each 'action' so that it snaps into place. This is actually pretty easy and has a certain charm but takes a little getting used to. `generalize` is just

```
return . runIdentity :: Monad m => Identity a -> m a
```

Notice that no signature in the second module uses a class constraint.

Comment: Thanks very much this is exactly the sort of thing I was hoping for. I need to do some reading to better understand the difference.

Comment: @Chris I added a version using 'hoist' 'lift' etc as you originally intended so you could see how it works. It's a different approach that just uses the transformer types and no classes (which are in mtl)  It unfortunately isn't a real option here because `RandT` doesn't have an `MFunctor` instance.

Comment: @Chris the first is the natural solution when you are using state, reader, writer, random and a few other 'effects'. With things like `conduit` or `pipes` you are dealing with a monad transformer that can't be represented so easily by an "mtl style" class and then the direct `lift` and `hoist` approach becomes more natural. The latter approach tends to give clearer error messages since it doesn't use type classes, but the `mtl` route is less verbose.

Comment: I just noticed `mapRandT` so actually you can do this the 'MFunctor' way, and edited to reflect this. I could have used `mapRandT` directly, but defined `hoistRandT` to match the type that `hoist` would have.

Answer (score 0):

Two options, plus a bonus one:

1. A basic solution would be generalising your types from `State` and `Rand` to `StateT` and `RandT`. Remember that `State s` is just a synonym for `StateT s Identity`, and analogously for `Rand`:

   ```
   somethingInRandom :: Monad m => RandT StdGen m Int
   somethingThatModifiesState :: Monad m => Int -> StateT MyState m ()
   somethingInStateAndRand :: Monad m => StateT MyState (RandT StdGen m) Int
   ```

   You don't need to change the body of your computations, as you have implemented them in terms of methods of `MonadState` and `MonadRandom`, which work out of the box for all monads built with `StateT` and `RandT` respectively. When using `somethingInRandom`, though, you need to slip in a `lift` to promote it to your `StateT`-transformed monad:

   ```
   test :: StateT MyState (RandT StdGen IO) ()
   test = do
       x  <- lift somethingInRandom
       _  <- somethingThatModifiesState x
       _  <- somethingInStateAndRand
       -- etc.
   ```
2. There is a nicer alternative, though: Since, as I mentioned above, your implementations are in terms of the `MonadState` and `MonadRandom`, you can, as bheklilr suggests, generalise the types in terms of those classes. That has two advantages over the first solution: you don't need the `lift` for `somethingInRandom` any longer, and your code will need no further changes if you, for instance, stack another transformer layer atop `StateT` or switch to a `MonadRandom` instance other than `RandT`:

   ```
   somethingInRandom :: MonadRandom m => m Int
   somethingThatModifiesState :: MonadState MyState m => m ()
   somethingInStateAndRand :: (MonadRandom m, MonadState MyState m) => m Int
   ```
3. Since you mentioned *mmorph*: if changing the signatures weren't an option for whatever reason (e.g. if you were using someone else's code), you would have to unwrap the `State`/`Rand` computations, slip in a `return . runIdentity` to change their inner monad and rewrap them. Since `return . runIdentity` is a monad morphism, there is a more convenient way to do that in the case of `StateT`, which has a [`MFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.9/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:hoist) instance:

   ```
   test = do
       -- etc.
       _  <- hoist generalize (somethingThatModifiesState x)
       -- etc.
   ```

   `generalize` from `Control.Monad.Morph` is literally `return . runIdentity`. There is further discussion of this trick in [*mmorph*'s documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.9/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#g:4).

[Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42231977/2751851) demonstrates solutions #2 and #3.